# Android : onCreateOptionsMenu called too late

Tags: android, android-actionbar, oncreateoptionsmenu

In my Activity I created a `MenuItem` that performs a clockwise animation in `ActionBar` when some data is loading. When `loadData()` is called the `MenuItem` has start the clockwise animation.

This works great, but when I first call `loadData()` inside `onCreate` callback the `menuItem` is not still available since `onCreateOptionsMenu()` has not been called yet, so my `menuItem` reference is still null and the animation can't start.

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Maybe this text from developer.android.com may help you: 

If you've developed your application for Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu() to create the options menu when the user opens the menu for the first time. If you've developed for Android 3.0 and higher, the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu() when starting the activity, in order to show items to the action bar.

Comment: I'm targeting my app for Android 3.0 and higher, so the system should call onCreateOptionsMenu() when the activity starts